# Select the Enum to classify a string based on the first word found

Tags: c#, strings, enum

I have written a small function that will check a string to see if it contains a certain word.

Depending on the word that is found first, the function will return the correct Enum value that needs to be used further down the line of the program.

Would there be a better way to check a string to see if it contains a certain Enum value?
The thing that gives me a little alarm bell in my head is that i am checking the same string 5 times in this function.

**Enum**

```
 public enum QuestionIdentifier
{

    Wie,
    Wat,
    Waarom,
    Wanneer,
    Hoe,
    Andere

}
```

**Function**

```
private QuestionIdentifier IdentifyQuestion(string vQuestion)
    {
        //QuestionToLower
        string vQTL = vQuestion.ToLower();

        if (vQTL.Contains("wie"))
        {
            return QuestionIdentifier.Wie;

        }else if (vQTL.Contains("wat"))
        {
            return QuestionIdentifier.Wat;

        }else if (vQTL.Contains("waarom"))
        {
            return QuestionIdentifier.Waarom;

        }else if (vQTL.Contains("wanneer"))
        {
            return QuestionIdentifier.Wanneer;

        }else if (vQTL.Contains("hoe"))
        {
            return QuestionIdentifier.Hoe;

        }else
        {
            return QuestionIdentifier.Andere;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can utilise the `Enum` class which can shorten your code significantly and it will be easier for future updates

```
private static QuestionIdentifier IdentifyQuestion(string vQuestion)
{
    //QuestionToLower
    string vQTL = vQuestion.ToLower();
    string[] enumNames = Enum.GetNames(typeof(QuestionIdentifier));
    foreach (var enumName in enumNames)
    {
        if (vQTL.Contains(enumName.ToLower()))
        {
            return (QuestionIdentifier) Enum.Parse(typeof(QuestionIdentifier), enumName);
        }
    }
    return QuestionIdentifier.Andere;
}
```

or with LINQ

```
private static QuestionIdentifier IdentifyQuestion(string vQuestion)
{
    string vQTL = vQuestion.ToLower();
    string[] enumNames = Enum.GetNames(typeof(QuestionIdentifier));
    string enumValueName = enumNames.FirstOrDefault(x => vQTL.Contains(x.ToLower()));
    return enumValueName != null
        ? (QuestionIdentifier) Enum.Parse(typeof(QuestionIdentifier), enumValueName)
        : QuestionIdentifier.Andere;
}
```

Now you can add as much types as you want in your enum without even touching this method it will still work and find your newly created type.

**Update**

As [@t3chb0t](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/150860/long-if-statement-to-select-correct-enum-value-in-a-string#comment284047_150863) pointed in the comments there is a way to avoid calling `.ToLower()` on both the input string and the enum value by using the `.IndexOf()` overload which accepts different comparison types :

```
private static QuestionIdentifier IdentifyQuestion(string vQuestion)
{
    string[] enumNames = Enum.GetNames(typeof(QuestionIdentifier));
    string enumValueName =
        enumNames.FirstOrDefault(x => vQuestion.IndexOf(x, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0);
    return enumValueName != null
        ? (QuestionIdentifier)Enum.Parse(typeof(QuestionIdentifier), enumValueName)
        : QuestionIdentifier.Andere;
}
```

Comment: `Enum.Parse` has an overload for case handling where you can specify`ignoreCase: true` - no need to `ToLower` so does the `Contains` method support a similar parameter, a `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` ;-)

Comment: Does that looks better @t3chb0t ?

Comment: It's an improvement but... it still can crash on `Enum.Parse` because if the case of the value does not match the enum name `Parse` won't accept it without `ignoreCase: true`. I think the best alternative is to use `Enum.TryParse<T>`here.

Comment: `enumValueName ` is always the same as the value in the enum. It's taken directly from the enum names, `TryParse` is redundant here

Comment: oh, crap, you're right

Answer (score 2):

If someone likes LINQ you can do it with one long chain of extensions and a coalesce `??` operator at the end:

```
return 
    Enum
    .GetValues(typeof(QuestionIdentifier))
    // The array is type-less so you need to cast each value first
    .Cast<QuestionIdentifier>()
    // Check if the string contains the value and get it or null
    .Select(x => vQuestion.Contains(x.ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? x : (QuestionIdentifier?)null)
    // Get first non-null value
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.HasValue)
    // Nothing found so use the default
    ?? QuestionIdentifier.Andere;
```

---

The default `Contains` does not accept a `string` but only `char` so let's create an extension that does:

```
public static bool Contains(this string str, string value, StringComparison stringComparison)
{
    return 
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) &&
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) &&
        str.IndexOf(value, stringComparison) >= 0;
}
```

Comment: @denis of course, fixed, thx

Comment: @denis `Contains` should accept a string... well, it's a case for a new extension, using the `IndexOf` is too much work for such a simple task like this.

Comment: Haha that's something useful to add indeed.

Comment: Your Contains method isn't making use of the third parameter

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 thx, fixed, I've fixed it once already and later replaced it with the invalid version when edited again lol

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate the enum

```
public static QuestionIdentifier QuestionIdentifierContains(string question)
{
    foreach (QuestionIdentifier questionIdentifier in Enum.GetValues(typeof(QuestionIdentifier)))
    {
        if (question.IndexOf(questionIdentifier.ToString(), StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
            return questionIdentifier;
    }
    return QuestionIdentifier.Andere;
}
```

As already pointed out String.Contains does not support ignore case but [IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425(v=vs.110).aspx) of does support ignore case.

Not as pretty but can use ToUpper (or ToLower)

```
public static QuestionIdentifier QuestionIdentifierContainsUpper(string question)
{
    string questionUpper = question.ToUpper();
    foreach (QuestionIdentifier questionIdentifier in Enum.GetValues(typeof(QuestionIdentifier)))
    {
        if (questionUpper.Contains(questionIdentifier.ToString().ToUpper()))
            return questionIdentifier;
    }
    return QuestionIdentifier.Andere;
}
```

Comment: I tested and the first answer from dennis is faster